# Negative positioning absolute element in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to negative positioning an absolute simple element. It works fine in ALL browser except in Firefox. The blue handler box should be positionned in the middle of top border instead as you can see on Chrome, IE or Safari. Is there any turnaround to fix this issue with Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
    padding-top: 10em
}

[draggable] {
    outline: 1px dashed #0099FF;
 cursor: move;
    position: relative
    }


.handler {
 width: 34px;
 height: 16px;
 background-color: #0099FF;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: -8px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div draggable="true" class="parent col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Services</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                <div class="handler"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `*[draggable]`? can't find anything that says a bare attribute selector is (il)legal css, however...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border` instead of using `outline`.

```css
body {
    padding-top: 10em
}

[draggable] {
    /* Use border */
    border: 1px dashed #0099FF;
 cursor: move;
    position: relative
    }


.handler {
 width: 34px;
 height: 16px;
 background-color: #0099FF;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: -8px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div draggable="true" class="parent col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Services</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                <div class="handler"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Artefact Does it fix your problem?

Comment: ABSOLUTELY! You are wy hero :)

Comment: The reason why I was using outline is 1px border is moving content when hovered.

Comment: @Artefact Do you have any problem now?

Comment: Yes in fact the border and the handler are hidden and should be diplayed on hover. With nested draggable element, the border vs outlet is moving elements. This is not good :(

Comment: @Artefact Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94728/discussion-between-artefact-and-alireza-safian).